# convolutional layer - trainable weights TensorFlow2

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow2.0

I am using TF2.5 & Python3.8 where a conv layer is defined as:

```
Conv2D(
    filters = 64, kernel_size = (3, 3),
    activation='relu', kernel_initializer = tf.initializers.GlorotNormal(),
    strides = (1, 1), padding = 'same',
)
```

Using a batch of 60 CIFAR-10 dataset as input:

```
x.shape
# TensorShape([60, 32, 32, 3])
```

Output volume of this layer preserves the spatial width and height (32, 32) and has 64 filters/kernel maps applied to the 60 images as batch-

```
conv1(x).shape
# TensorShape([60, 32, 32, 64])
```

I understand this output.

Can you explain the output of:

```
conv1.trainable_weights[0].shape
# TensorShape([3, 3, 3, 64])
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the formula used to compute the number of trainable parameters in a conv layer = [{(m x n x d) + 1} x k]

where,
m -> width of filter; n -> height of filter; d -> number of channels in input volume; k -> number of filters applied in current layer.

The 1 is added as bias for each filter. But in case of TF2.X, for a conv layer, the bias term is set to False. Therefore, it doesn't appear as in formula.